# My cart doesn't remove items after pressing the remove button

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, web-applications, cart

I need my cart item to remove when clicked on remove, but it is not working. The cart page just refresh and ends its execution. I need to create a working cart function to remove items from it.

This is my template file - views.html:

```
{% extends 'pro/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% if empty %}
<div class="container">
  <h1 style="text-align:center">{{ empty_message }}</h1>
</div>
{% else %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Total:{{ cart.total }}</th>

    <th></th>
  </tfoot>
  {% for item in cart.cartitem_set.all %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ item.product }} {% if item.variations.all %}<ul>
      {% for subitem in item.variations.all %}
      <li>{{ subitem.category|capfirst }}:{{ subitem.title|capfirst }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>{% endif %}</td>
    <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.product.price }}</td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'remove_from_cart' item.id %}">Remove</a></td>
  </tr
  {% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Cart,CartItem
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from app.models import Product,Variation


def cart(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        the_id = None
    if the_id:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
        context = {'cart':cart}
    else:
        empty_message = "you have notthing in your cart.Carry on your shoopping"
        context = {'empty':True,"empty_message":empty_message}

    template = 'cart/view.html'
    return render(request,template,context)

def remove_from_cart(request,id):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))

    cartitem = CartItem.objects.get(id=id)

    cartitem.cart = None
    cartitem.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))


def add_to_cart(request,slug):
    request.session.set_expiry(None)

    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        new_cart = Cart()
        new_cart.save()
        request.session['cart_id'] = new_cart.id
        the_id = new_cart.id
    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)

    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass

    product_var = []

    if request.method == "POST":
        qty = request.POST['qty']
        for item in request.POST:
            key = item
            val = request.POST[key]
            try:
                v = Variation.objects.get(product=product,category__iexact=key,title__iexact=val)
                product_var.append(v)
            except:
                pass


        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(cart=cart,product=product)



        if len(product_var)>0:
            cart_item.variations.add(*product_var)
        cart_item.quantity = qty
        cart_item.save()


        new_total = 0
        for item in cart.cartitem_set.all():
            line_total = float(item.product.price)*item.quantity
            new_total += line_total

        request.session['item_count'] = cart.cartitem_set.count()
        cart.total = new_total
        cart.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```

And this is my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path,include
from app import views
from cart.views import cart,add_to_cart,remove_from_cart

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('s/',views.search,name='search'),
    path('cart/',cart,name='cart'),
    path('cart/<slug:slug>/',add_to_cart,name='add_to_cart'),
    path('cart/<int:id>/',remove_from_cart,name='remove_from_cart'),
    path('products/',views.all,name='products'),
    path('produc/<slug:slug>/',views.single,name='single_product'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: its running without errors

Comment: Hi Avi! I would suggest rewording your question, as currently it is very vague and a lot of users will just skip it. Make it more language/platform/framework focussed.

Comment: @nabster sir i willl defintely review it.